# Tensorflow speech-commands Scores of Listen and Recognize are different

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, speech-recognition, tensorflow.js

I have a `recognizer` and used its `listen` function to get the Float32Array array from [SpeechCommandRecognizerResult.spectrogram.data](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/speech-commands/src/types.ts#L367), then concatenated the array using [concatenateFloat32Arrays](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/2d269c257bf59a3c878d823d3e3973d7954500bc/speech-commands/src/generic_utils.ts#L45) util function

When I use the Float32Array that I got from `listen` function and use it as a parameter [input](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/speech-commands/src/types.ts#L85) in `recognize` function, the score is different and the score of the second label is almost always zero

The scores of `listen` function are expected, but the scores of `recognize` function are not expected

[Example in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tfjs-listen-recognize-scores-iyrjd)

What did I wrong to get unexpected scores of recognize function with an input parameter?